# How to set defaults for scales in ChartJS?

Tags: chart.js

How do I set defaults for `scales` values in ChartJS?

I have a series of similar graphs on one page, and I want to set some common defaults for them, to avoid duplicating that config for each one.  As a specific example, I want to remove vertical gridlines.  To do that inline is simple:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        x: {
            grid: {
                display: false
            },
        },
    },
}
```

That works fine, but I don't want to duplicate that n-times on the page.  I tried setting that as a default like so:

```
Chart.defaults.scales.x.grid.display = false;
```

But this throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'grid')

I find the docs very confusing, but maybe [this page](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/) is suggesting a format like:

```
Chart.defaults.scales[scaleID].grid.display = false;
```

[A different section of that same page](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#default-scales) suggests that "*the default `scaleID` ... are `x` and `y`*".  So I tried:

```
Chart.defaults.scales[x].grid.display = false;
```

But this throws a new error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

I gave up guessing with the docs and tried:

```
console.dir(Chart.defaults.scales);
```

And found there are only types like `category` and `time` present.  I tried setting them like:

```
Chart.defaults.scales.category.grid.display = false;
```

And got another new error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display')

```js
// Works fine
Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.display = false;

// None of these work
// Chart.defaults.scale.x.grid.display = false;
// Chart.defaults.scales.x.grid.display = false;
// Chart.defaults.scales[x].grid.display = false;
// Chart.defaults.scales.xAxisID.grid.display = false;
// Chart.defaults.scales.category.grid.display = false;

const data = {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    }]
};

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
        // This works, but how to set it as a default?
        /*
            x: {
                grid: {
                    display: false
                },
            },
        */
        },
    }
};

const chart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('chart'),
    config
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-QSkVNOCYLtj73J4hbmVoOV6KVZuMluZlioC+trLpewV8qMjsWqlIQvkn1KGX2StWvPMdWGBqim1xlC8krl1EKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing this up, [explaining it to the duck](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/), and confirming each error I solved the problem myself.  I thought I'd post anyway as I spent some hours on this and my own searching did not turn up anything which helped, maybe it will help a future someone or even future me.

The clue was in the new error I got in the last thing I tried:

```
Chart.defaults.scales.category.grid.display = false;
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display')
```

So `grid` is undefined.  As a wild desperate guess I tried:

```
Chart.defaults.scales.category.grid = {
    display: false
};
```

And it works.